# Convert PDF to bytes on client rather than on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My asp.Net MVC app needs to store a byte array that represents a user-selected PDF file per record in the database. The SQL column is a Varbinary(max).

The approach I'm contemplating is to use Telerik's (most awesome) KendoUI Upload control to asynchronously upload the selected PDF to the controller method.  The controller method converts the PDF to bytes using classes in the System.IO namespace, and I return that byte array in a Json result.  I have an event handler on the page that waits for this result, and then writes that byte array to a hidden input, which then gets saved with the rest of the record when the user clicks the save button, posting the Form back to the server.

My gut feel is that I have some nasty inefficiency here...

1. the pdf is sent to the server (probably already in some form of byte array created by the Upload control).
2. the result of the upload method returns a byte array back to the page.
3. the page then submits the form postback, containing the byte array that will be saved to the database.

My thinking is that step 3 is the only network traffic required here.  Is there any way that conversion from a PDF document to a byte array can happen on the client instead?  What clever JavaScript/jQuery would do this?

Comment: (Un)fortunetly JavaScript cannot directly interact with files. This would be a serious security issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

> The controller method converts the PDF to bytes using classes in the
>   System.IO namespace, and I return that byte array in a Json result. I
>   have an event handler on the page that waits for this result, and then
>   writes that byte array to a hidden input, which then gets saved with
>   the rest of the record when the user clicks the save button, posting
>   the Form back to the server.

Change this logic to:

> The controller method converts the PDF to bytes using classes in the
>   System.IO namespace, and saves it to the database and returns a Json result.
>   indicating the success or failure of this operation. No more hidden fields, no
>   more byte arrays. When the client submits the form, the file should no
>   longer be sent to the server because it was already sent and stored in
>   the database. So in the controller action that will process the form
>   submission I associate the other form fields with the file in the
>   database record.

Comment: +1: Remember that you need some cleaning mechanism with this. User may decide not to make the final save (or he's connection may simply crash).

Comment: Though this isn't the answer I was hoping for...it is an interesting approach, and I'll +1 it.  The problem is that the record being edited doesn't exist in the database yet...in fact, the user might even choose to cancel out of saving the record.  I'd have to build in some additional logic to tie together the 2 separate acts of saving the byte array, and then later saving the actual record to which the byte array relates.

Comment: @ShawndeWet Yep, you will have to do that. I don't think there is any other way since JavaScript cannot interact with files. But it is not really difficult. Do first save, send id, do second save, you're done!

Comment: You could have a status column in your database that will initially be set to some default value when you save the file, and only once you complete the full transaction set it to `completed`. Then run a job every night to clean up all uncompleted transactions.